# Save from listbox to .txt file and load from it on start

Tags: vb6, listbox

If i have listox with name `lstPerioda` and textbox with name `txtDescription` . I want to select and save/load different text in `txtdescription` for each item in list.

Something like this

http://pokit.org/get/img/fade9475ab42b1eaaf1b25320aed5a2d.jpg

Those are some kind of notes what i will do. All this should be saved to some kind of document. I was think about `.txt` file or maybe `database` what do you think ??

Edit:
I can write the values from listbox to `.txt` file and load it again

```
    Private Sub Command1_Click()
Open "Listbox.txt" For Output As #1
For i = 0 To List1.ListCount - 1
    Print #1, List1.List(i)
Next
Close
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()

List1.AddItem "Monday"
List1.AddItem "Tuesday"
List1.AddItem "Wednesday"
List1.AddItem "Thursday"
List1.AddItem "Friday"
List1.AddItem "Saturday"
List1.AddItem "Sunday"
End Sub
```

But how can i make different text which will be saved to some .`txt` file and read from it each time i start application. Also be available for update.

So basicly if i write to description that Today is Monday i want to save that to file and each time i select monday from listbox it show's me that description

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read text from .txt by the listbox request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686012/read-text-from-txt-by-the-listbox-request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will read each single line in a textfile and add it to a List String

Edit:

```
Dim lists As New List(Of String)

Private Sub Main()
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim TS As TextStream
    Dim Final As String
    Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
    Set TS = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\text.txt", ForReading)
    Final = TS.ReadAll

    Dim pattern As String = "\r\n|\r|\n"
    Dim result() As String = Regex.Split(Final, pattern)
    For Each s As String In result
        lists.Add(s)
    Next
End Sub
```

Note: Add this as an import first for Regex

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

EDIT2:

You can display your text when listbox items selected as following:

```
Private Sub ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged()
    Select ListBox1.SelectedIndex
        Case 0
            TextBox1.Text = lists.Item(0)
        Case 1
            TextBox1.Text = lists.Item(1)
        Case 2
            TextBox1.Text = lists.Item(2)
        Case 3
            TextBox1.Text = lists.Item(3)
        Case 4
            TextBox1.Text = lists.Item(4)
        Case 5
            TextBox1.Text = lists.Item(5)
    End Select
End Sub
```

Assuming your listbox and textbox contains 6 different items and textlines

Comment: thank you for your answer. So i need to add 7 diferent `.txt` files for each day. And depends which day is selected in listbox load text from that file ?

Comment: @Anel_Hodzic is this what you wanted?

Comment: Hmh this is just another method for listbox. I managed somehow to save/read the values from `.txt` to `listbox` . Now i want when i chose something from `listbox` example "Monday" in `txtdescription` i have custom text for Monday and want to show it. Same for Tuesday's and other days.  So basically i add for different days different things which i need to do and whenever i run the application i chose day and it show's me things i need to to that selected day. I hope i explain a bit more

Comment: @Anel_Hodzic You can use reference in vb6 but as for reading files check the edit

Comment: `List(Of ...)` I also VB.Net while the FSO is primarily for VBScript. If you're going to answer VB6 questions, can you use VB6 code?

Comment: @Deanna i haven't used VB since 9 years ago, so pardon my synthesis