# Read text from .txt by the listbox request

Tags: text, vb6

I want to make something like this 
[image]

Example : Something like planer i write things i need to do for specific days and when i choose in a listbox day it show's me what i need to do.

So because it will remember data it need's to be saved on some kind of .txt or database .

I can add/load items from listbox like this

```
 Private Sub Command1_Click()
      Open "Listbox.txt" For Output As #1
          For i = 0 To list1.ListCount - 1
          Print #1, list1.List(i)
      Next
      Close
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    list1.AddItem "Monday"
    list1.AddItem "Tuesday"
    list1.AddItem "Wednesday"
    list1.AddItem "Thursday"
    list1.AddItem "Friday"
    list1.AddItem "Saturday"
    list1.AddItem "Sunday"
    End Sub
```

But the main problem is text save. How can i save the text from a textbox for a specific day or edit it . So when i click on Monday it show's me the custom text i entered for monday.

Do i need to make a new file for each day in a week like 7 files or there is a easier way ??

Comment: @Plutonix thank for your answer. It need to work weekly. Its one week planner. Date isn't matter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Save from listbox to .txt file and load from it on start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680002/save-from-listbox-to-txt-file-and-load-from-it-on-start)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessary to make separate files for each listbox item.

Here's my sample project; I made a couple of changes to your form layout:

[image: Screenshot 1]

When an item is clicked in the list at the left, the text field will provide the text associated with the item. Update the item by typing something into / changing the same field.

```
Option Explicit

Private FileStr As String, StrArr() As String

Private Sub cmdSave_Click()

    Dim I As Long
    Open FileStr For Output As #1
    For I = 0 To lbxItems.ListCount - 1
        Print #1, lbxItems.List(I) & "," & StrArr(I)
    Next I
    Close #1

End Sub

Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()

    StrArr(lbxItems.ListIndex) = txtDescript

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim TempStr As String
    FileStr = App.Path & "\planner.txt"
    Open FileStr For Input As #1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, TempStr
        J = InStr(TempStr, ",")
        lbxItems.AddItem Left$(TempStr, J - 1)
        TempStr = Mid$(TempStr, J + 1)
        ReDim Preserve StrArr(I)
        StrArr(I) = TempStr
        I = I + 1
    Loop
    Close #1

End Sub

Private Sub lbxItems_Click()

    txtDescript = StrArr(lbxItems.ListIndex)

End Sub
```

The code is designed so that it can be used with other items that are inserted into the "planner.txt" file manually. If you do this, make sure that you follow the item name with a comma ( , ).

If you copy and paste the code straight into your form code module as is, make sure to update the control names as necessary.